# Why is my firefox extension only posting data when on localhost and not on any other websites?

Tags: javascript, server, firefox-addon-webextensions

I have a Spring server and am using xhttp to post data to the server from a firefox extension. The data will only send from localhost and not from any other websites.

'''javascript

```
function sendo(keys) {
    try{
        var xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
        xhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
               if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
                   alert(this.responseText);
               }
        };

        xhttp.open("POST", "http://localhost:8080/index", true);
        xhttp.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/json");

        xhttp.setRequestHeader("X-Data", keys);
        xhttp.send("{\"name\": \"Urmi\"}");
        console.log("Sent " + keys);
    }
    catch(e){
        console.log(e);
    }
}
```

'''

When this function is called while on localhost, everything executes correctly and the keys are correctly posted to the server. When on any other website, the code seemingly runs, as the console.log at the end of the try statement runs, but nothing is ever posted to the server.

Comment: Enable CORS in back end

Comment: @charlietfl I just tried that and it still isn't working. I added a creatCORSrequest function and am calling that now.